# How to detect duplicate values in session array php?

Tags: php, html

im creating a student subject reservation that will add subject from a table row.I would like to detect the presence of duplicate values,then echo  if the  values are detected.

For example, given the following array:

```
$c=0;

        while($c<=$counter){
            if($_SESSION["S['$c']"]==""){
            echo "-";
            }
        $array1=array($_SESSION["lect['$c']"],$_SESSION["labt['$c']"],$_SESSION["Day['$c']"] ,$_SESSION["lday['$c']"]);
        if(count(array_unique($array1))<count($array1)){
            echo "Duplicate entry found in array";
        }
        else{
                    echo "<tr><td>".$_SESSION["S['$c']"] . " </td>
                <td>".$_SESSION["lec['$c']"] . "<br/>".$_SESSION["lab['$c']"] . "</td>
                <td>".$_SESSION["lect['$c']"] . "<br/>".$_SESSION["labt['$c']"] . "</td>
                <td>".$_SESSION["Day['$c']"] . "<br/>".$_SESSION["lday['$c']"] . "</td>
                <td>".$_SESSION["room['$c']"] . "<br/>".$_SESSION["lroom['$c']"] . "</td></tr><br>";
             $unit=$_SESSION["lec['$c']"] + $_SESSION["lab['$c']"];
               $units= $units+$unit;
        }
```

but when i add the same value the value will add again but when i add another it display echo "Duplicate entry found in array"; where did i got wrong? sorry for my bad English   thanks in advance if my code is wrong please give me some advice

here is the click event that well add to another table:

```
$i=0;
$b =1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ){


echo "<tr><td>".$row['Subject']."<input type='hidden' name='subj[$i]' value=".$row['Subject']."></td>
<td>".$row['Lec']."<br/>".$row['Lab']."<input type='hidden' name='leclab[$i]' value=".$row['Lec']."><input type='hidden' name='lab[$i]' value=".$row['Lab']."></td>

<td>".$row['Descriptive']."<input type='hidden' name='desc[$i]' value=".$row['Descriptive']."></td>
<td>".$row['Day']."<br/>".$row['Labday']."<input type='hidden' name='daylabday[$i]' value=".$row['Day']."><input type='hidden' name='labday[$i]' value=".$row['Labday']."></td>

<td>".$row['LecTime']."<br/>".$row['LabTime']."<input type='hidden' name='lectlabt[$i]' value=".$row['LecTime']."><input type='hidden' name='labtime[$i]' value=".$row['LabTime']."></td>

<td>".$row['Room']."<br/>".$row['Labroom']."<input type='hidden' name='roomlabroom[$i]' value=".$row['Room']."><input type='hidden' name='labroom[$i]' value=".$row['Labroom']."></td>

<td><input id='send' name='reserv[$i]' type='submit' value='Add' onclick='addRow('myTable')' /> </td></tr>";

$i++;


}
}
```

Here is sample of the output but all i wanted is to echo the error with the same value added on the table how i can prevent it?

[image]

Comment: You're rather abusing array key notation. You should be using something like `$_SESSION['lect'][$c]` to make proper subarrays, instead of embedding array subscripts into key names.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix using [array_unique](http://php.net/array_unique) and [array_diff](http://php.net/array_diff) firstly to clean duplicates and then make a diff to get array containing only duplicated values

Comment: can you explain more sir i cant really understand cuz im new in php

Answer (score 0):

[`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) will count repeated values. then you can [filter out](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) those with count 1 and see which ones are repeated

Comment: can you explain more sir i cant really understand cuz im new in php

Comment: can you add some example input and output for your code? i'm not sure that what you asked for is what you need, after re-reading your code

Comment: if i add value1 to the table and add it again it echo the same value i cant post sample picture.

Comment: sir i post some picture above hope it help to understand

Comment: if i understand the picture, the error is the duplicated row on the reserve table, right? in that case, any of our answer is valid, and you should rephrase your question to "duplicate row" instead of "duplicate values"

Comment: no sir i actually add the second row! my first add is 0 and the second is 1 but i add same value in the table the problem is how to catch the error with the same day and same time sorry for late reply